# inspect.getargvalues() throws exception "AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'f_code'"

Tags: python, introspection

I'm trying to use Python's `inspect` module (in Python 2) to show information about the function that called the current function, including its arguments.

Here's a simple test program:

```
import inspect

def caller_args():
    frame = inspect.currentframe()
    outer_frames = inspect.getouterframes(frame)
    caller_frame = outer_frames[1]
    return inspect.getargvalues(caller_frame)

def fun_a(arg1):
    print caller_args()

def fun_b():
    fun_a('foo')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fun_b()
```

And this happens when I run it:

```
$ python getargvalues_test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "getargvalues_test.py", line 16, in <module>
    fun_b()
  File "getargvalues_test.py", line 13, in fun_b
    fun_a('foo')
  File "getargvalues_test.py", line 10, in fun_a
    print caller_args()
  File "getargvalues_test.py", line 7, in caller_args
    return inspect.getargvalues(caller_frame)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/inspect.py", line 829, in getargvalues
    args, varargs, varkw = getargs(frame.f_code)
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'f_code'
```

I've googled that AttributeError exception, but with no luck. What am I doing wrong?

(I've since found the problem, so I'm asking-and-answering this here so anyone who has this problem in future will find the answer here.)

Answer (score 7):

[This similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24615270/in-python-get-the-argument-passed-to-a-function-as-a-string-within-the-function/) helped me discover the problem.

The [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#the-interpreter-stack) for the `inspect` module mentions both "frame records" and "frame objects", and explains the difference.

- `inspect.currentframe()` returns a frame *object*, but
- `inspect.getouterframes()` returns a list of frame *records*.

The mistake in the code above is not extracting the frame object from the frame record of the calling function, and passing `inspect.getouterframes()` the frame record instead of the frame object. (Note that `inspect.getouterframes()` doesn't check that its argument is a frame object.)

Here's the fixed definition of `caller_args()` (with the change to the assignment to `caller_frame`):

```
def caller_args():
    frame = inspect.currentframe()
    outer_frames = inspect.getouterframes(frame)
    caller_frame = outer_frames[1][0]
    return inspect.getargvalues(caller_frame)
```

Which runs as desired:

```
$ python getargvalues_test_fixed.py
ArgInfo(args=['arg1'], varargs=None, keywords=None, locals={'arg1': 'foo'})
```

Answer (score -1):

cause of error

> AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'f_code'

in your function

> def caller_args()

is that caller_frame is an array of which you need item [1][0] as argument for

> inspect.getargvalues(...)

this works :

```
currframe = inspect.currentframe()
callerframe = inspect.getouterframes(currframe, 2)
inspect.getargvalues(callerframe[1][0])
```

Also, the getargvalues function returns 4 values. First three are unimportant in this case, fourth contains JSON like format key/value list of callerframe arguments

```
 _,_,_,values = inspect.getargvalues(callerframe[1][0])
 for i in values:
     argsstring += str(i) + ' : ' + str(values[i])
```

My test looks like this :

```
import inspect

def log(text):
    currframe = inspect.currentframe()
    callerframe = inspect.getouterframes(currframe, 2)
    _,_,_,values = inspect.getargvalues(callerframe[1][0])
    argsstring = ''
    for i in values:
        argsstring += str(i) + ' : ' + str(values[i])
    print('name of file : ' + callerframe[1][1])
    print('name of function : ' + callerframe[1][3])
    print('line number : ' + str(callerframe[1][2]))
    print('caller function arguments : ' + argsstring)

def doTest(text):
    log(text) 

doTest('this is a test')
```