# packing named arguments into a dict

Tags: python, dictionary, keyword-argument

I know I can turn function arguments into a dictionary if the function takes in `**kwargs`.

```
def bar(**kwargs):
    return kwargs

print bar(a=1, b=2)
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

However, is the opposite true? Can I **pack** named arguments into a dictionary and return them? The hand-coded version looks like this:

```
def foo(a, b):
    return {'a': a, 'b': b}
```

But it seems like there must be a better way. Note that i am trying to avoid using `**kwargs` in the function (named arguments work better for an IDE with code completion).

Comment: `return locals()` once you don't have any other variables in your code

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/582206/432913) answer to the same question has a comment underneath linking to [this](http://kbyanc.blogspot.co.uk/2007/07/python-aggregating-function-arguments.html) blog post, which does what you want, and takes care or an edge cases which iCodez's answer misses.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for [`locals`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals):

```
>>> def foo(a, b):
...     return locals()
...
>>> foo(1, 2)
{'b': 2, 'a': 1}
>>> def foo(a, b, c, d, e):
...     return locals()
...
>>> foo(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
{'c': 3, 'b': 2, 'a': 1, 'e': 5, 'd': 4}
>>>
```

Note however that this will return a dictionary of *all* names that are within the scope of `foo`:

```
>>> def foo(a, b):
...     x = 3
...     return locals()
...
>>> foo(1, 2)
{'b': 2, 'a': 1, 'x': 3}
>>>
```

This shouldn't be a problem if your functions are like that given in your question.  If it is however, you can use [`inspect.getfullargspec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getfullargspec) and a [dictionary comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) to filter `locals()`:

```
>>> def foo(a, b):
...     import inspect # 'inspect' is a local name
...     x = 3          # 'x' is another local name
...     args = inspect.getfullargspec(foo).args
...     return {k:v for k,v in locals().items() if k in args}
...
>>> foo(1, 2) # Only the argument names are returned
{'b': 2, 'a': 1}
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks for the disclaimer; I am looking for this functionality within a class, so I'm making the method static.