# Checking arguments of a function in ipython

Tags: python, python-2.7, ipython

I'm using the jupyter ipython notebook by anaconda.

IS there a quick way of looking at the arguments of a function like we do in `RStudio`? For e.g. `?merge` displays documentation for merge in the lower right window of RStudio.

I was specifically looking for arguments of `matplotlib.figure()` which I found here but this is time consuming: http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.figure

Found this post related to the question: [Getting list of parameter names inside python function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582056/getting-list-of-parameter-names-inside-python-function)

but not sure if it is the same question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type `matplotlib.figure?` at the command prompt, and it'll give you the signature and documentation:

```
In [1]: import matplotlib

In [2]: matplotlib.figure?
Type:        module
String form: <module 'matplotlib.figure' from '~/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.pyc'>
File:        ~/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py
Docstring:
The figure module provides the top-level
:class:`~matplotlib.artist.Artist`, the :class:`Figure`, which
contains all the plot elements.  The following classes are defined

:class:`SubplotParams`
    control the default spacing of the subplots

:class:`Figure`
    top level container for all plot elements
```

From the [IPython introduction](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/2/interactive/tutorial.html#exploring-your-objects):

> ### Exploring your objects
>
> Typing `object_name?` will print all sorts of details about any object, including docstrings, function definition lines (for call arguments) and constructor details for classes. To get specific information on an object, you can use the magic commands `%pdoc`, `%pdef`, `%psource` and `%pfile`

You can also use the standard Python [`help()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#help); the output is a little more verbose and not coloured, like the ipython `object?` command however.

Answer (score 3):

You can try `help(matplotlib.figure)` after importing `matplotlib`

Comment: Sure, but this is **ipython**, which has `object?`, much shorter and more helpful.

Comment: @MartijnPieters ok...you mean `help` wouldnt work in IPython...i'm not familiar with it, i confess

Comment: No, `help()` works, but ipython has *better* facilities available.