# How to convert all arguments to dictionary in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, args, keyword-argument

I would like to my function `func(*args, **kwargs)` return one dictionary which contains all arguments I gave to it. For example:

```
func(arg1, arg2, arg3=value3, arg4=value4)
```

should return one dictionary like this:

```
{'arg1': value1, 'arg2': value2, 'arg3': value3, 'arg4': value4 }
```

Comment: looks like the same problem here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582056/getting-list-of-parameter-names-inside-python-function

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem; since you could simply call `dict(arg1=arg1, arg2=arg2, arg3=value3, arg4=value4)`. What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: @chepner
`arg1 = { 'x': 'X', y': 'Y'}`
`arg2 = 2`, function
`func(arg1, arg2, arg3= 3)`
should return `{'x': 'X', y': 'Y, 'arg2': 2, 'arg3':3}

Comment: OK, that's a significantly different outcome than what you are asking about in your question.

Answer (score 28):

You can use `locals()` or `vars()`:

```
def func(arg1, arg2, arg3=3, arg4=4):
    print(locals())

func(1, 2)

# {'arg3': 3, 'arg4': 4, 'arg1': 1, 'arg2': 2}
```

However if you only use `*args` you will not be able to differentiate them using `locals()`:

```
def func(*args, **kwargs):
    print(locals())

func(1, 2, a=3, b=4)

# {'args': (1, 2), 'kwargs': {'a': 3, 'b': 4}}
```

Comment: Your first output seems strange, arg3&arg4 have values 1&2 instead of 3&4. It should be : `{'arg1': 1, 'arg2': 2, 'arg3': 3, 'arg4': 4}`

Comment: @Nuageux Indeed, was just a copy-paste error. I fixed it.

Comment: What if i give dictionary as argument? I will get this
`{ 'args': ({'argX': 'x', 'argY': 'y}, 'arg1': 1) , kwargs': {}} ` instead o this `{'arg1': 1, 'argX': 'x', 'argY': 'y'} `

Comment: @NikolaMijušković see the "However" part of my answer

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for `locals()`

```
def foo(arg1, arg2, arg3='foo', arg4=1):
    return locals()

{'arg1': 1, 'arg2': 2, 'arg3': 'foo', 'arg4': 1}
```

Output:

```
{'arg1': 1, 'arg2': 2, 'arg3': 'foo', 'arg4': 1}
```

Comment: `locals` is too broad if there are local variables other than the arguments.

Comment: @chepner i presume if you call the as soon as the function is called then it will only list arguments? You could store this as a new variable i think?

Answer (score 2):

If you can't use `locals` like the other answers suggest:

```
def func(*args, **kwargs):
    all_args = {("arg" + str(idx + 1)): arg for idx,arg in enumerate(args)}
    all_args.update(kwargs)
```

This will create a dictionary with all arguments in it, with names.