# how to optimze if "string" in kwargs.values():

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a class which will accept any kwargs.

```py
class testcode():
    def check_values(**kwargs):
        if "Test1" in kwargs.values():
           return function1
        elif "Test2" in kwargs.values():
           return function2...
        ...
        else:
           return function20



test=testcode(Input1="Test1",Something="blablabla",Otherthing="blabalbalbalb2")
```

As the number of kwarg is not fixed, I may write lots of if/elif, can I use a dict to replace the if/elif/else?

update:
@deceze, the reason why I ignore some args is that I want to simulate some AWS API. for example, AWS S3 is using

```py
response = client.list_multipart_uploads(
    Bucket='string',
    Delimiter='string',
    EncodingType='url',
    KeyMarker='string',
    MaxUploads=123,
    Prefix='string',
    UploadIdMarker='string'
)
```

I want to write a class to mock the function. And the when I test, I can return the value based on UploadIdMarker.

```py
class testcode():
    def list_multipart_uploads(**kwargs):
        if "Test1" in kwargs.values():
           return s3_string1
        elif "Test2" in kwargs.values():
           return s3_string2
        ...
        else:
           return s3_string100

test=testcode(Bucket='string',
    Delimiter='string',
    EncodingType='url',
    KeyMarker='string',
    MaxUploads=123,
    Prefix='string',
    UploadIdMarker='Test1'")
```

Comment: yes, you can ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert all arguments to dictionary in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44412617/how-to-convert-all-arguments-to-dictionary-in-python)

Comment: That doesn't seem terribly sensible either way…?! You're just looking at any *value* and ignore the keywords themselves? So `testcode(foo='bar', bar='bar')` and `testcode(baz='blarg', quux='bar')` would return the same value? How does that make any practical sense?

Comment: Why you passing arguments to class, you need to call "check_values".Check on it

Comment: There's the Y in the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), what's the X?

Comment: Wouldn't it make the most sense to use a ["Python switch"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60211/476) as `return {'Test1': ..., ...}[kwargs['UploadIdMarker']]`…?

Comment: Why are you accepting arbitrary keyword arguments if you don't care about the keyword and don't (depending on your version of Python) care about which argument you see first?

Comment: kwargs is just a dict. If you want this to depend on UploadIdMarker then test with 'UploadIdMarker' in kwargs, and get the value with kwargs['UploadIdMarker']