# Is there a way to convert named function arguments to dict

Tags: python, function, dictionary, parameter-passing, named

I am trying to find out if there is a way to convert named arguments to `dict`.

I understand using `**kwargs` in place of individual named arguments would be pretty straight forward.

```
def func(arg1=None, arg2=None, arg3=None):
    # How can I convert these arguments to {'arg1': None, 'arg2': None, 'arg3': None}`
```

Comment: Could you please show what you indend to do with that?

Comment: Because the answer is just `{'arg1': None, 'arg2': None, 'arg3': None}`

Comment: I can't imagine a use case for this. Would you be able to post the use-case as well explaining why you need this kind of structure?

Comment: `func(..., **kwargs)` is for when you're converting named args on the **calling**-side to a dict on the **function-definition** side. But you want to convert one into the other, **both on the function-definition side**. That would be weird. Please explain why you want to do this (i.e. also show the calling-side syntax, and state what actual problem you're trying to solve).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting list of parameter names inside python function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582056/getting-list-of-parameter-names-inside-python-function)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `locals()` to get the local arguments:

```
def func(arg1=None, arg2=None, arg3=None):
    print(locals())

func()  # {'arg3': None, 'arg2': None, 'arg1': None}
```

Comment: This does not work as the locals() method returns a dictionary with all the local variables and symbols for the current program.