# reassign values to args of a function

Tags: python

i have a function with about 20-30 parameters

```
def function (a,b,c,d,e,....):

     ....
```

those paramenters may have any value, including "None". 
I want to reasign a specifique string to each var that has the value "None" before my function does its magic.

But I dont want to have a huge block of code such as:

```
if a is None:
     ....
if b is None: ....
```

How can I go through each var and reasign its value if the condition is met?

ty

Comment: What's the string?

Comment: Use classes to group related parameters. Delegate the `if`s to the classes. Don't write 30 parameter functions

Comment: use a dictionary?

Comment: Use default parameters that aren't None?

Comment: Why not simply [default argument values](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values) ?

Comment: If I use default parameters that arent None, wouldnt they get overwritten when I call the function with the new arguments that are None?

Comment: using a dictonary does sound simpler. also found a solution at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582056/getting-list-of-parameter-names-inside-python-function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you are doing something pretty exotic, this kind of thing is usually better handled by collecting the variables in a data structure, e.g. a `dict` like so:

```
def function(**kwargs):
    default = 42
    for key, val in kwargs.items():
        if val is None:
            kwargs[key] = default
    ...
    print(kwargs)

# Example call
function(a=1, b=None)
```

You can assign to individual variables using the magic of [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec), but it's generally not advised. Furthermore, it's not clear to me how one can successfully use this inside of a function as e.g. `exec('a = 42')` doesn't actually change the value of the local `a` variable.

Comment: ty. thats what i was looking for. fyi: the function takes a bunch of strings as parameters, but what generates the strings can also produce a None element, depending on user interaction (html component).

Comment: This assumes that the function is called with keyword arguments; if I try `function(1,None)`, it will fail.

Answer (score 1):

If you have so many arguments to the function, then you can try using iterable unpacking operator `*` instead of explicitly defining each argument. In that you you will have more control over the contents of the arguments:-

```
def function(*args):
    args = list(args)
    for x, y in enumerate(args):
        if y is None:
            args[x] = "default_value"
    print(args)
```

Then do a function call similar to :-

```
function(123, 3, None, "hello")
```

**OUTPUT:-**

```
[123, 3, 'default_value', 'hello']
```

Comment: This does not address *changing* parameters, just *identifying* them.

Comment: if I use *args can i still name my parameters?

Comment: @epattaro then your parameters becomes a tuple, so you can index them off it

Comment: Thanks @ScottHunter For pointing that out. Edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: This fails if called with named arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not recommending doing this, but if you insist:

```
def function(a,b,c,d,e,...):
    myvars = locals()         # Get a dictionary of parameters
    arg_names = myvars.keys() # Get their names
    for k in arg_names:       # Replace the ones whose value is None
        if myvars[k] == None:
            myvars[k] = 'None'
```

Comment: that works even better. ty. i should problaby be using a dictionary as an input, or is there a better solution?