# Is there a built-in way to simulate assignment of values to arguments?

Tags: python, parameter-passing, python-decorators, keyword-argument

I have a decorator that I use to suppress and log exceptions within a function. The code is something like this:

```py
def log_exceptions(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            print(args, kwargs)  # also log what arguments caused the exception
        return ret
    return wrapper
```

A problem here is that, it is hard to manually match the printed argument values to the argument names of the function, because positional arguments could also go inside `kwargs`, and there may be `args` and `kwargs` arguments in the inner function as well. So, it would be useful to match the `args` and `kwargs` values in the wrapper with argument names in the inner function.

My question is then, is there a built-in way to do this matching? If not, what would be an elegant way to implement it?

Comment: Also see [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582056/getting-list-of-parameter-names-inside-python-function)

Comment: @Pynchia: That's part of the solution, but it doesn't show how to perform the matching. (Admittedly, it is the hard part - implementing `bind` is more straightforward and requires less knowledge than implementing `signature` - but reimplementing `bind` would still be a lot of pointless work.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the signature can be determined, then `inspect.signature(func).bind(*args, **kwargs)` does the job.

[`inspect.signature(func)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.signature) (lowercase s) attempts to compute a [`Signature`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.Signature) object (capital S) representing a callable's signature, and the resulting `Signature`'s `bind` method matches the signature against provided arguments, returning a [`BoundArguments`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.BoundArguments) object. The `arguments` attribute of the resulting object is an ordered mapping of parameter names to values, excluding arguments that fell back on default values.

Here's an example of how you might use it:

```
import inspect

try:
    sig = inspect.signature(func)
except (TypeError, ValueError):
    print('Could not determine function signature.')
else:
    try:
        bound = sig.bind(*args, **kwargs)
    except TypeError:
        print('Could not bind arguments to function signature.')
        print('Signature:', sig)
        print('Positional arguments:', args)
        print('Keyword arguments:', kwargs)
    else:
        # You can use bound.apply_defaults() to include defaults
        print('Bound arguments (defaults not included):')
        for name, value in bound.parameters:
            print('{}: {!r}'.format(name, value))
```