# Nice Python Decorators

Tags: python, decorator

How do I nicely write a decorator?

In particular issues include: compatibility with other decorators, preserving of signatures, etc.

I would like to avoid dependency on the decorator module if possible, but if there were sufficient advantages, then I would consider it.

Related

- [Preserving signatures of decorated functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147816/preserving-signatures-of-decorated-functions) - much more specific question. The answer here is to use the third-party decorator module annotating the decorator with @decorator.decorator

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Writing a good decorator is no different then writing a good function.  Which means, ideally, using docstrings and making sure the decorator is included in your testing framework.

You should definitely use either the `decorator` library or, better, the `functools.wraps()` decorator in the standard library (since 2.5).

Beyond that, it's best to keep your decorators narrowly focused and well designed.  Don't use `*args` or `**kw` if your decorator expects specific arguments.  And *do* fill in what arguments you expect, so instead of:

```
def keep_none(func):
    def _exec(*args, **kw):
        return None if args[0] is None else func(*args, **kw)

    return _exec
```

... use ...

```
def keep_none(func):
    """Wraps a function which expects a value as the first argument, and
    ensures the function won't get called with *None*.  If it is, this 
    will return *None*.

    >>> def f(x):
    ...     return x + 5
    >>> f(1)
    6
    >>> f(None) is None
    Traceback (most recent call last):
        ...
    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'
    >>> f = keep_none(f)
    >>> f(1)
    6
    >>> f(None) is None
    True"""

    @wraps(func)
    def _exec(value, *args, **kw):
        return None if value is None else func(value, *args, **kw)

    return _exec
```

Answer (score 6):

Use functools to preserve the name and doc. The signature won't be preserved.

Directly from the [doc](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html).

```
>>> from functools import wraps
>>> def my_decorator(f):
...     @wraps(f)
...     def wrapper(*args, **kwds):
...         print 'Calling decorated function'
...         return f(*args, **kwds)
...     return wrapper
...
>>> @my_decorator
... def example():
...     """Docstring"""
...     print 'Called example function'
...
>>> example()
Calling decorated function
Called example function
>>> example.__name__
'example'
>>> example.__doc__
'Docstring'
```

Comment: Its good ettiquete to make wiki answers to your own questions.