# Tab completion of decorated functions in IPython Notebook

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

In the following example code below, we have an undecorated function `fun()` and a decorated one `wrappedfun()`.

For the undecorated function `fun`, pressing TAB in IPython notebook after the opening parenthesis following the function name shows the call signature as `fun(x=0, y=1)` but for the decorated version `wrappedfun` you get the completion as `wrappedfun(*args, **kwargs)`. Is there any way to tell IPython to display the original call signature during TAB completion?

```
from functools import wraps

def mywrapper(func):
''' simple wrapper '''
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print('inside wrapper')
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

def fun(x=0, y=1):
    ''' Docstring for fun '''
    return x + y

@mywrapper
def wrappedfun(x=0, y=1):
    ''' Docstring for wrapped another fun '''
    return x + y
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem lie in there :

```
def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    print('inside wrapper')
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
```

even if it `@wraps(func)` , `wrapper` might take more arguments, so the signature you see is the signature of `wrapper`. There is no way to magically know what you want to do.

This will not be specific to IPython, and can be found elsewhere on stack overflow like [Preserving signature of decorated function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147816/preserving-signatures-of-decorated-functions). Hope this will solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks! The link you provided answered my question.