# decorator - Setting a wrapped functions argument names and values

Tags: python, decorator, args, keyword-argument

Is it possible to give a wrapped function the arg and kwargs names of the function it is wrapping? I need to do this because decorators that are applied later use the arg names of the underlying function.

```
def wrapper(func):
    def wrapped(<func args and kwargs names and values>):
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
```

So if the func been passed in was foo(x,y=3), the returned wrapped function would have the signature wrapped(x, y=3) instead of the usual wrapped(*args, **kwargs).

--Edit--

Just found that this is a duplicate of [Preserving signatures of decorated functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147816/preserving-signatures-of-decorated-functions) . Thanks for the answers anyway

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question, isn't this what you expect ?

```
>>> def wrapper(func):
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        print args, kwargs
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped

>>> @wrapper
def foo(x, y=3):
    return x + y

>>> foo(3)
(3,) {}
6
>>> foo(3, 5)
(3, 5) {}
8
>>> foo(3, y=5)
(3,) {'y': 5}
8
```