# Python; enforce two functions implement the same interface?

Tags: python

I want to do something, for *functions*, not *classes*, like

```
def function_A(param1, param2 = "default_param_2")

def function_B(__signature of A__)
```

So that whenever I change the interface of `A`, this is automatically updated in `B`. Is there a notion of an "abstract base interface" for functions or a mechanism to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how useful this is but decorators may give you a least part of what you are looking for.  Consider:

```
from functools import wraps

def abi(f):
    @wraps(f) #preserves name/doc of wrapped function
    def function_A(param1, param2='param2'):
        print(param1, param2)
    return function_A

@abi
def function_B(*args, **kw):
    "I'm function_B but I'm REALLY function_A.  Look there for params."
    pass
```

Defining *args and **kw for function_B makes it flexible for function_A to change its signature.  Any parameters passed into function_B will be mapped to function_A's following the normal rules; too many args, multiple values for argument, etc. will raise TypeErrors.

If you change the signature of function_A, any calls to function_B that still match can be called successfully (assuming the module has been reloaded).  The rest will fail obviously and you'll need to update the calls to function_B.

Hope this helps!  YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

I would not do this at runtime, and you cannot change the signature automatically but you can definitely test that in your testing suite using the [inspect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) module.

For instance:

```
import inspect

def foo(bar, baz=42, **kwargs):
    pass

for param in inspect.signature(foo).parameters.values():
    print('%s is %s' % (param.name, param.kind))
```

This will print:

```
bar is POSITIONAL_OR_KEYWORD
baz is POSITIONAL_OR_KEYWORD
kwargs is VAR_KEYWORD
```

You can use this to compare the signature of functions in your test suite. Check out the [inspect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) module for other things you can introspect.

Answer (score 1):

Under Python 3 you can easily get the signature:

```
>>> from inspect import signature
>>> def A(a, b='default'):
...    pass
>>> sig=signature(A) 
>>> print(sig)
(a, b='default')
```

Problem is, there is not much you can do with that without being really hacky.

You can compare a function's signature to another:

```
def A(a, b='default'):
    pass

def B(a, b='something else'):
    if signature(A) != signature(B):
        print('Yo, need to update me!')
    else:
        print('all good in B land')
```

But you cannot dynamically update B to match A.

Comment: this is a helpful first start, let me play around with this, thanks.

Comment: You might be able to do something with [decorators](http://stackoverflow.com/a/147878/298607)