# Preserve Signature in Decorator python 2

Tags: python, python-2.7, typeerror, python-decorators

I am writing a decorator which will catch TypeError for incorrect number of arguments in a function call and will print a customised message. The code is here:

```
import inspect

def inspect_signature(f):
    def decorate(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            f(*args, **kwargs)
        except TypeError as e:
            print('Failed to call "{}" with signature {}. Provided args={} and kwargs={}.'.format(
                f.__name__, inspect.getargspec(f).args, args, kwargs))
        return f
    return decorate


@inspect_signature
def func(foo, bar):
    pass
func('a')
func('a', 'b')
```

I get the following output:

```
Failed to call "func" with signature ['foo', 'bar']. Provided args=('a',) and kwargs={}.
Called successfully with foo=a, bar=b
ArgSpec(args=[], varargs='args', keywords='kwargs', defaults=None)
```

The function signature is empty. Please suggest me a solution how can I retain it?

PS: I am using python2 and cannot switch to python3.

Answer (score 0):

You missed this here.  **func(*foo, **bar)**

In your case `func('a')` was not working as you gave fixed arg for it.

You need to pass a variable number of arguments to your function

```
@inspect_signature
def func(*foo, **bar):
    pass
```

Comment: I am not passing variable number of arguments to the function. I have fixed two arguments. I know `func('a')` will not work so for that I have written a decorator which will print a customized message instead of python inbuilt error message but my original function signature are lost. So I want to retain it.

Comment: @python_user So what was the definition for your original signature function?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to [Preserving signatures of decorated functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147816/preserving-signatures-of-decorated-functions/147878#147878).

In a word, you can use **`decorator`** module in Python2 and Python3. When you use Python3.4+, you can use `inspect.wraps` to Preserving signatures of decorated functions.

If you don't want to use `decorator` module, you can use `eval` to make a decorator. In General, `eval` is unpopular, so, `decorator` module may be the best solution in Python2.

Comment: You probably mean `functools.wraps`. Note that it does not actually preserve behavioral signature as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55163816/7262247.
Also note that `decorator` (and the generalization of its core, `makefun`) rely on `compile` + `exec` :)
See https://github.com/micheles/decorator/blob/master/src/decorator.py and https://github.com/smarie/python-makefun/blob/master/makefun/main.py