# Python decorator (closure version) that preserves signature

Tags: python, python-2.7, decorator

My decorator is "closure-style"; it does some work before returning the decorated function.

Borrowing from this famous question: [Preserving signatures of decorated functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147816/preserving-signatures-of-decorated-functions/147878#147878)

```
def args_as_ints(f):

    time.sleep(1) # hard at work

    def g(*args, **kwargs):
        args = [int(x) for x in args]
        kwargs = dict((k, int(v)) for k, v in kwargs.items())
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return g
```

`functools.wraps` does not preserve the signature in Python 2.

```
from functools import wraps

def args_as_ints(f):

    time.sleep(1) # hard at work

    @wraps(f) 
    def g(*args, **kwargs):
        args = [int(x) for x in args]
        kwargs = dict((k, int(v)) for k, v in kwargs.items())
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return g


@args_as_ints
def funny_function(x, y, z=3):
    """Computes x*y + 2*z"""
    return x*y + 2*z

help(funny_function)
```

shows

```
Help on function funny_function in module __main__:

funny_function(*args, **kwargs)
    Computes x*y + 2*z
```

The `decorator` module doesn't seem to support this style of decorator.

Also related: [Preserve Signature in Decorator python 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42359024/preserve-signature-in-decorator-python-2)

Comment: Have you read the part about `functools.wraps`?

Comment: Please clarify. What is your question? Your decorator works OK on my machine: https://www.ideone.com/9RajlT. Note that that famous question is ten years old so it may recommend techniques that are no longer necessary.

Comment: @NilsWerner: which part? I tried it, it doesn't preserve the signature

Comment: Please amend your question with all your attempts

Comment: Ah sorry, I missed what you meant...

Comment: Oh, I missed the "preserves signature" bit in the title. So the problem is that the documentation doesn't show `x, y, z=3`... That's a real concern. Thanks for clarifying :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to find the answer here: https://decorator.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tests.documentation.html#dealing-with-third-party-decorators

```
def args_as_ints(f):

    time.sleep(1)

    def g(*args, **kwargs):
        args = [int(x) for x in args]
        kwargs = dict((k, int(v)) for k, v in kwargs.items())
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    return decorator.FunctionMaker.create(
        f, 'return decfunc(%(signature)s)',
        dict(decfunc=g, __wrapped__=f))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`wrapt`](https://pypi.org/project/wrapt/) module.

Keep in mind that `wrapt` decorators have a different interface than standard python decorators. I strongly recommend reading the [`wrapt` documentation](https://wrapt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/decorators.html). Anyway, here's a basic implementation of your decorator with `wrapt.decorator`:

```
import wrapt

def args_as_ints(f):
    time.sleep(1) # hard at work

    @wrapt.decorator
    def g(f, instance, *args, **kwargs):
        args = [int(x) for x in args]
        kwargs = dict((k, int(v)) for k, v in kwargs.items())
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    return g(f)  # apply the decorator to the function
```

Note that my implementation completely ignores the `instance` argument, so it won't work correctly for instance methods.

It does, however, maintain the decorated function's signature:

```
Help on function funny_function in module __main__:

funny_function(x, y, z=3)
    Computes x*y + 2*z
```