# How to dynamically change signatures of method in subclass?

Tags: python, class, methods, signature

When using **classmethod** to dynamic change the method in subclass, how to dynamic change signatures of method?

**example**

```
import inspect

class ModelBase(object):

    @classmethod
    def method_one(cls, *args):
        raise NotImplementedError

    @classmethod
    def method_two(cls, *args):
        return cls.method_one(*args) + 1

class SubClass(ModelBase):
    @staticmethod
    def method_one(a, b):
        return a + b

test = SubClass()

try:
    print(inspect.signature(test.method_two))
except AttributeError:
    print(inspect.getargspec(test.method_two).args)
```

I want `test.method_two` to get the signatures of `test.method_one`. How to rewrite parent class `ModelBase`?

I have read about [Preserving signatures of decorated functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147816/preserving-signatures-of-decorated-functions). In python3.4 +, `functools.wraps` helps to preserve signatures of decorated functions. I want to apply it to class method.

when uses `functools.wraps`, I need to assign decorated method's name. But how to access decorated method outside `classmethod` in this situation?

```
from functools import wraps

class ModelBase(object):

    @classmethod
    def method_one(cls, *args):
        raise NotImplementedError

    @classmethod
    def method_two(cls):
        @wraps(cls.method_one)
        def fun(*args):
            return cls.method_one(*args) + 1
        return fun
```

`method_two` returns a wrapped function, but I must use it with `test.method_two()(*arg)`. This method is not directly.

Answer (score 1):

If this is only for introspection purpose you could override `__getattribute__` on `ModelBase` and every time `method_two` is accessed we return a function that has the signature of `method_one`.

```
import inspect

def copy_signature(frm, to):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return to(*args, **kwargs)
    wrapper.__signature__ = inspect.signature(frm)
    return wrapper


class ModelBase(object):

    @classmethod
    def method_one(cls, *args):
        raise NotImplementedError

    @classmethod
    def method_two(cls, *args):
        return cls.method_one(*args) + 1

    def __getattribute__(self, attr):
        value = object.__getattribute__(self, attr)
        if attr == 'method_two':
            value = copy_signature(frm=self.method_one, to=value)
        return value


class SubClass(ModelBase):
    @staticmethod
    def method_one(a, b):
        return a + b


class SubClass2(ModelBase):
    @staticmethod
    def method_one(a, b, c, *arg):
        return a + b
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> test1 = SubClass()
>>> print(inspect.signature(test1.method_two))
(a, b)
>>> test2 = SubClass2()
>>> print(inspect.signature(test2.method_two))
(a, b, c, *arg)
```

Comment: Thank you! It's for CodeGen. To do codegen for method_two, it need the signatures of method_one.