# __call__ from metaclass shadows signature of __init__

Tags: python, spyder, metaclass

I would like to have in the code underneath that when i type  `instance_of_A = A(`, that the name of the supposed arguments is `init_argumentA` and not `*meta_args, **meta_kwargs`. But unfortunatally, the arguments of the `__call__` method of the metaclass are shown.

```
class Meta(type):    
    def __call__(cls,*meta_args,**meta_kwargs):
        # Something here
        return super().__call__(*meta_args, **meta_kwargs)

class A(metaclass = Meta):
    def __init__(self,init_argumentA):
        # something here 

class B(metaclass = Meta):
    def __init__(self,init_argumentB):
        # something here
```

I have searched for a solution and found the question [How to dynamically change signatures of method in subclass?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45626647/how-to-dynamically-change-signatures-of-method-in-subclass)
 and [Signature-changing decorator: properly documenting additional argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34402773/signature-changing-decorator-properly-documenting-additional-argument). But none, seem to be completely what I want. The first link uses inspect to change the amount of variables given to a function, but i can't seem to let it work for my case and I think there has to be a more obvious solution. 
The second one isn't completely what I want, but something in that way might be a good alternative.

Edit: I am working in Spyder. I want this because I have thousands of classes of the Meta type and each class have different arguments, which is impossible to remember, so the idea is that the user can remember it when seeing the correct arguments show up.

Comment: You have to be more specific about *when* they should be shown. Are you working in a Python shell, IDLE, IPython, Jupyter, Visual Studio code, something else? Do you want them to show in the IDE at all or is this about `help()` or documentation builds?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, i updated the question and hope that it is more clear now

Comment: this seems to be a problem with IDE, not with Python itself

Comment: okay, I cannot reproduce that. If I use your code (with `pass` inside the `__init__`s) in spyder it shows the signature of `A.__init__` and `B.__init__` when I print `A(` or `B(`. Could you add further information, such as the spyder version, the python version, a working code sample (your code produces an IndentationError) and maybe a screenshot of the incorrect suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok - even though the reason for you to want that seems to be equivocated, as any "honest" Python inspecting tool should show the `__init__` signature, what is needed for what you ask is that for each class you generate a dynamic metaclass, for which the `__call__` method has the same signature of the class's own `__init__` method.

For faking the `__init__` signature on `__call__` we can simply use `functools.wraps`. (but you might want to check the answers at
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/33112180/108205 )

And for dynamically creating an extra metaclass, that can be done on the `__metaclass__.__new__` itself, with just some care to avoud infinite recursion on the `__new__` method - threads.Lock can help with that in a more consistent way than a simple global flag.

```
from functools import wraps
creation_locks = {} 

class M(type):
    def __new__(metacls, name, bases, namespace):
        lock = creation_locks.setdefault(name, Lock())
        if lock.locked():
            return super().__new__(metacls, name, bases, namespace)
        with lock:
            def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
                return super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
            new_metacls = type(metacls.__name__ + "_sigfix", (metacls,), {"__call__": __call__}) 
            cls = new_metacls(name, bases, namespace)
            wraps(cls.__init__)(__call__)
        del creation_locks[name]
        return cls
```

I initially thought of using a named parameter to the metaclass `__new__` argument to control recursion, but then it would be passed to the created class' `__init_subclass__` method (which will result in an error) - so the Lock use.

Answer (score 2):

Using the code you provided, you can change the `Meta` class

```py
class Meta(type):
    def __call__(cls, *meta_args, **meta_kwargs):
        # Something here
        return super().__call__(*meta_args, **meta_kwargs)


class A(metaclass=Meta):
    def __init__(self, x):
        pass
```

to

```py
import inspect

class Meta(type):
    def __call__(cls, *meta_args, **meta_kwargs):
        # Something here

        # Restore the signature of __init__
        sig = inspect.signature(cls.__init__)
        parameters = tuple(sig.parameters.values())
        cls.__signature__ = sig.replace(parameters=parameters[1:])

        return super().__call__(*meta_args, **meta_kwargs)
```

Now IPython or some IDE will show you the correct signature.

Answer (score 1):

I found that the answer of [@johnbaltis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60262239/4013571) was 99% there but not quite what was needed to ensure the signatures were in place.

If we use `__init__` rather than `__call__` as below we get the desired behaviour

```
import inspect

class Meta(type):
    def __init__(cls, clsname, bases, attrs):

        # Restore the signature
        sig = inspect.signature(cls.__init__)
        parameters = tuple(sig.parameters.values())
        cls.__signature__ = sig.replace(parameters=parameters[1:])

        return super().__init__(clsname, bases, attrs)

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        print(f'Instanciated: {cls.__name__}')

class A(metaclass=Meta):
    def __init__(self, x: int, y: str):
        pass
```

which will correctly give:

```
In [12]: A?
Init signature: A(x: int, y: str)
Docstring:      <no docstring>
Type:           Meta
Subclasses:     

In [13]: A(0, 'y')
Instanciated: A
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps the author but in my case I needed to change `inspect.signature(Klass)` to `inspect.signature(Klass.__init__)` to get signature of class `__init__` instead of metaclass `__call__`.