# How to avoid code duplication in init during inheritance? Extending xgb.XGBClassifier to handle feature names

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I have concrete problem with extending `xgb.XGBClassifier` class, but it could be framed as general OOP question.

My implementation is based on: https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/python-package/xgboost/sklearn.py

Basically, I want add feature names handling when provided data is in pandas DataFrame.

A few remarks:

- `XGBClassifierN` has the same parameters in `__init__` as base class `xgb.XGBClassifier`,
- there is an additional attribute `self.feature_names`that is set by later `fit` method.
- Rest could be done by mix-ins.

It works.

What bothers me, is this wall of code in `__init__`. It was done by copy-paste defaults and every time when `xgb.Classifier` will change it had to be updated.

Is there any way to concise express idea that child class `XGBClassifierN` has the same parameters and defaults as parent class `xgb.XGBClassifier` and do later things like `clf = XGBClassifierN(n_jobs=-1)`?

I've tried to use only `**kwargs` but it doesn't work out (interpreter starts to complain that there is no `missing` parameter (no pun intentented), and to make it work basically you need to set a few more parameters).

```
import xgboost as xgb

class XGBClassifierN(xgb.XGBClassifier):
    def __init__(self, base_score=0.5, booster='gbtree', colsample_bylevel=1,
              colsample_bynode=1, colsample_bytree=1, gamma=0,
              learning_rate=0.1, max_delta_step=0, max_depth=3,
              min_child_weight=1, missing=None, n_estimators=100, n_jobs=1,
              nthread=None, objective='binary:logistic', random_state=0,
              reg_alpha=0, reg_lambda=1, scale_pos_weight=1, seed=None,
              silent=None, subsample=1, verbosity=1, **kwargs): 
        super().__init__(base_score=base_score, booster=booster, colsample_bylevel=colsample_bylevel,
              colsample_bynode=colsample_bynode, colsample_bytree=colsample_bytree, gamma=gamma,
              learning_rate=learning_rate, max_delta_step=max_delta_step, max_depth=max_depth,
              min_child_weight=min_child_weight, missing=missing, n_estimators=n_estimators, n_jobs=n_jobs,
              nthread=nthread, objective=objective, random_state=random_state,
              reg_alpha=reg_alpha, reg_lambda=reg_lambda, scale_pos_weight=scale_pos_weight, seed=seed,
              silent=silent, subsample=subsample, verbosity=verbosity, **kwargs)
        self.feature_names = None

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        self.feature_names = list(X.columns)
        return super().fit(X, y)

    def get_feature_names(self):
        if not isinstance(self.feature_names, list):
            raise ValueError('Must fit data first!')
        else:
            return self.feature_names

    def get_feature_importances(self):
        return dict(zip(self.get_feature_names(), self.feature_importances_))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've tried to use only **kwargs but it doesn't work out.

"doesn't work" is most useless possible description of a problem. You should instead document exactly what happens with all relevant details.

This being said, if your question is "how do I avoid retyping the full parent method signature etc", you were actually quite close with `**kwargs`, just missing the positional args part `*args`:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): 
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.feature_names = None
```

Just note that this makes the signature useless for inspection (pydoc, the builtin `help()` function, IDE autocompletion etc).

EDIT: actually, there might be a way - at least, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147816/preserving-signatures-of-decorated-functions), `functools.wraps()` CAN preserve the signature of a decorated function. There's also [Michele Simionato's "decorator" lib](https://github.com/micheles/decorator) that provides the same service, so you should be able to reuse this code to have your cake and eat it too !-)

Comment: Thanks. I've updated the question. Basically interpreter complains that required parameters are not set, but interesting it works for LogisticRegression from scikit-learn, with minor change: no *args. Btw. I'd want to have a signature.

Comment: @QuantChristo I'm afraid your added details are still not enough - we'd need a *proper* [mcve] here to diagnose the issue. But anyway: if you want to be able to use any tool relying on inspection, you have no other choice (that I know of at least)  than maintaining a complete copy of the parent's method signature.

Comment: Many thanks Bruno for help. I need inspection. I'll to dig deeper: I'll check `xgb.XGBClassifier().get_params() ` in init and meta-programming. If I find solution, I'll post it.

Comment: @QuantChristo looks like my python-foo are not what they use to be - cf my edited answer.