# When I decorate a python function, VS Code shows the function's help, instead of the wrapper's , when hovered

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, tooltip, python-decorators, docstring

This question was raised some time ago: [When I decorate a python function, VS Code shows the wrapper's help, instead of the function's , when hovered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64054165/when-i-decorate-a-python-function-vs-code-shows-the-wrappers-help-instead-of)

Apparently it was fixed by PyLace. I have now the opposite problem: I want to include the docstring of the wrapper in the tooltip.

Decorator:

```
def magic:
  def wrapper:
     result = doSomeMagic()
     return result
  wrapper.__doc__ = f'{func.__doc__} and some other stuff'
  return wrapper
```

Now I have a function where I use the decorator:

```
@magic
def sayHello():
   '''A simple function to print Hello'''
   print("Hello")
```

If I call `help(sayHello)` I get back `A simple function to print hello and some other stuff`
This is all good! But if I use the tooltip for the function hello it would just give me the docstring from the function: `A simple function to print Hello` but I want to have the wrapper docstring in the tooltip...

I tried to include in the wrapper:

```
func.__doc__ = wrapper.__doc__
```

No success so far. Does someone has an idea how to achieve this in VSCode or PyCharm? Is there a way to influence the shown tooltips?

Comment: Statically, VSCode doesn't know what `magic` does to `sayHello`. It would have to execute the code to see that a new docstring was provided. I don't know what it used to do to simulate that.

Comment: I was already afraid that it used some static analysis... but I am still wondering if it was possible because it seemed like it was from the old question