# Why function __name__ returns wrapper function name and not the name of the function the code sits in?

Tags: python, function, python-decorators, args

```
def logging_decorator(function):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print(f'This is {function.__name__}')
        output = function(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper


@logging_decorator
def a_function(a, b, c):
    print(f'This is the Function name {a_function.__name__}')
    return a * b * c

object = a_function(3, 4, 5)
```

Been playing around with python decorators and I don't understand the following:

Why does

```
print(f'This is the Function name {a_function.__name__}')
```

output 'This is the Function name wrapper'? Shouldn't the output be 'This is the Function name a_function' instead?

Comment: No, obviously not. What function do you think you are calling?

Comment: The name has to be of the wrapper; it’s wrapping the decorated function

Comment: The `@deco def foo` syntax is equivalent to ` def foo()... foo = deco(foo)`, what does your decorator return?

Comment: I'm calling the a_function.__name__ i'm not calling the wrapper.__name__ yet it still prints the wrapper function name

Comment: Try answers  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147816/preserving-signatures-of-decorated-functions

Comment: The variable `a_function` *refers to the value returned from your decorator*, which is the function you define inside as `def wrapper` and then you `return wrapper`, this is **crucial** to understand

Answer (score 0):

After your function is defined.

```py
a_function = def (a, b, c){...}
```

The wrapper will wrap your function. You can imaginate like this:

```py
a_function = logging_decorator(a_function)
```

And the function `logging_decorator` return a function name `wrapper`. Now, `a_function` is just a reference, that linked to function `wrapper`

To get what you expect, I tried this:

```py
from functools import wraps

def logging_decorator(function):
    @wraps(function)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print(f'This is {function.__name__}')
        output = function(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper


@logging_decorator
def a_function(a, b, c):
    print(f'This is the Function name {a_function.__name__}')
    return a * b * c

@logging_decorator
def b_function(a, b, c):
    print(f'This is the Function name {b_function.__name__}')
    return a * b * c

object = a_function(3, 4, 5)
object = b_function(3, 4, 5)
```

And it solve your problem.